# OpenCv MOG2 Backgroundsubtraction function is not working well on C++

Tags: c++, opencv, background-subtraction

Hello everyone I used MOG2 function in C# there was no problem but when i try to do same thing on C++ there is a strange result. I believe it's about image's channels but i couldn't fix it . I need a hand thanks .

```
Mat mask;

Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> sub ;
sub=createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
sub->apply(frame,mask);
```

This is a pretty simple define but the result is like this.

[The result of MOG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSeBt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem . The problem is defining the functions in the frame events.

So this `Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> sub ;` part must defined in the header file and `sub=createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();` must be defined in the click even not the frame event.

I hope this helps if anyone needs the solution.